# Is this normal? Cabinet/Backsplash install

Tags: drywall, concrete, kitchens, backsplash

We hired a contractor for our kitchen but are doing our own bathroom.

The contractor installed the wall cabinets directly on concrete and the base cabinets on top of ungrouted tile.

The contractor has cut pieces of drywall and adhered them to the exposed parts of the concrete that the backsplash will go onto. Is this normal? The drywall is not blue drywall and about 1/2 inch think. It covers part of the quartz counter top, the outlets sink in slightly (since they are behind the drywall).

Is the drywall solution normal since the cabinets are on concrete? I’ve never seen this before. [image][image][image]

Comment: Cabinets on concrete isn't normal where I'm from. The rest is just weird. Where are you? Got photos?

Comment: This sounds unusual why use concrete board and cover it with sheetrock? As far as ungrouted tile on the floor if it is wall to wall tile they are charging for work that has not been finished if you decide to change things later because the tile is there it is almost impossible to match even with some of the same grout sealed up at a later date. In addition it will provide a path for water to get to the sub floor with spills. A photo would be helpful of both areas to provide a better answer.

Comment: I assumed concrete block or poured concrete--not cement board. New2, please clarify.

Comment: It’s concrete block/poured concrete on the wall where the majority of the cabinets and sink are (it’s a wall shared with the adjoining unit - this is a condo in a condo apt building). Let me see if I can figure out how to add photos

Answer (score 2):

So many issues it’s hard to know where to start: 1) cabinets installed on concrete prior to wall finish, 2) cabinets installed on floor finish, 3) wall tiled without removing electrical wall plate, 4) countertop installed prior to wall oven/microwave cabinet, 5) base trim on island cabinet not flush with cabinet (1/8” gap at top of base trim), 6) countertop installed prior to wall finish, 7) cabinets and base installed prior to grout.

Yuck!

Comment: Flex duct for vent hood, no plaster rings on elect. boxes, ginger ale without vodka...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing done here is normal or a good idea for that matter. I repeat nothing!! Don’t pay anything for this messs tear it out, start over and quit using somebody else’s brother in law.